# python regular expression equivalent to /[^a-f0-9]/i

Tags: python, regex

Exactly what the question asks. 
Python equivalent to Javascript check if there is a character that is not a-f or 0-9. Case insensitive.

My try was

```
re.match('[^a-f0-9]',str,re.I)
```

EDIT:
My test

```
import re;

teststrA='7z';
testsrB='5k';
if re.match('[^a-f0-9]',teststrA,re.I) or re.match('[^a-f0-9]',teststrB,re.I):
    print 'found match';
else:
    print 'no match';
```

keeps saying "no match".

Comment: shouldn't it be `[^a-f0-9]`?

Comment: **cough** https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html **cough**

Comment: yes it should. Typo. I think my problem may be---does python register a returned match as true? so if(re.match...): if i find something

Comment: Yep it does. Still not catching outliers though...

Comment: Your try looks like it should work. How exactly are you calling `re.match`, and what's not working?

Comment: Don't leave the typo; this is a reference site, not a conversational one.  Edit the title to fix.

Comment: Also, neither of your test strings matches that regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be that Python's `re.match` is *anchored*.  So it will only return true if the regex matches at the beginning of the string.  If you want to see if it matches anywhere in the string, use `re.search` instead.

Note that `re.search` doesn't return a Boolean, but a `Match` object if anything matches, `None` otherwise.

Comment: THERE it is. Javascript has a global operator on match. Does python?

Comment: To loop over all the matches, use `re.finditer`.  Really, you should follow the link Jacob-It gave in his comment and read the documentation for the `re` module.  It's quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an offending character anywhere in the string (not just at the beginning), then you probably should use `search` instead of `match`.

```
re.search('[^a-f0-9]',str,re.I)
```

The return from that is a `Match` object if there is a match, the `None` singleton otherwise.  So you should be safe using it inside an `if` conditional in the way you proposed in your comments.

Comment: Thanks. Right answer. Mark answered it just seconds before you though :)